# "Cannot read property 'projection' of undefined" :webgl error in my 1st 3D geometry program

Tags: canvas, 3d, webgl

I am looking at webglfundamentals blog series and learning animations. Based on my understanding, I am trying to replicate [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-3d-step2.html) in a slightly different manner, such that I do not have dependency on util files of the blog series. I am unable to resolve this error:

```
Cannot read property 'projection' of undefined
    at createVertices.
```

```js
var gl,
    shaderProgram,
    vertices;

initGL();
createShaders();
createVertices();

function initGL() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  console.log(canvas);
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

function createShaders() {
  var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "3d-vertex-shader");
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "3d-fragment-shader");
  
  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

}

function createVertices() {
  vertices = [
   // left column
            0,   0,  0,
           30,   0,  0,
            0, 150,  0,
            0, 150,  0,
           30,   0,  0,
           30, 150,  0,
 
          // top rung
           30,   0,  0,
          100,   0,  0,
           30,  30,  0,
           30,  30,  0,
          100,   0,  0,
          100,  30,  0,
 
          // middle rung
           30,  60,  0,
           67,  60,  0,
           30,  90,  0,
           30,  90,  0,
           67,  60,  0,
           67,  90,  0
  ];
   

  
  //create buffer
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
  
  function radToDeg(r) {
    return r * 180 / Math.PI;
  }

  function degToRad(d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  var translation = [45, 150, 0];
  var rotation = [degToRad(40), degToRad(25), degToRad(325)];
  var scale = [1, 1, 1];
  var color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
  
  
  
  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");

  // lookup uniforms
  var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_color");
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_matrix");
  
   
   // webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Turn on the attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  
    // Create a buffer to put positions in
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

    // set the color
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);

    // Compute the matrices
    var matrix = m4.projection(gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight, 400);
    matrix = m4.translate(matrix, translation[0], translation[1], translation[2]);
    matrix = m4.xRotate(matrix, rotation[0]);
    matrix = m4.yRotate(matrix, rotation[1]);
    matrix = m4.zRotate(matrix, rotation[2]);
    matrix = m4.scale(matrix, scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);

    // Set the matrix.
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

    // Draw the geometry.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 18;  // 6 triangles in the 'F', 3 points per triangle
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

//m4 
var m4 = {

  projection: function(width, height, depth) {
    // Note: This matrix flips the Y axis so 0 is at the top.
    return [
       2 / width, 0, 0, 0,
       0, -2 / height, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 2 / depth, 0,
      -1, 1, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  multiply: function(a, b) {
    var a00 = a[0 * 4 + 0];
    var a01 = a[0 * 4 + 1];
    var a02 = a[0 * 4 + 2];
    var a03 = a[0 * 4 + 3];
    var a10 = a[1 * 4 + 0];
    var a11 = a[1 * 4 + 1];
    var a12 = a[1 * 4 + 2];
    var a13 = a[1 * 4 + 3];
    var a20 = a[2 * 4 + 0];
    var a21 = a[2 * 4 + 1];
    var a22 = a[2 * 4 + 2];
    var a23 = a[2 * 4 + 3];
    var a30 = a[3 * 4 + 0];
    var a31 = a[3 * 4 + 1];
    var a32 = a[3 * 4 + 2];
    var a33 = a[3 * 4 + 3];
    var b00 = b[0 * 4 + 0];
    var b01 = b[0 * 4 + 1];
    var b02 = b[0 * 4 + 2];
    var b03 = b[0 * 4 + 3];
    var b10 = b[1 * 4 + 0];
    var b11 = b[1 * 4 + 1];
    var b12 = b[1 * 4 + 2];
    var b13 = b[1 * 4 + 3];
    var b20 = b[2 * 4 + 0];
    var b21 = b[2 * 4 + 1];
    var b22 = b[2 * 4 + 2];
    var b23 = b[2 * 4 + 3];
    var b30 = b[3 * 4 + 0];
    var b31 = b[3 * 4 + 1];
    var b32 = b[3 * 4 + 2];
    var b33 = b[3 * 4 + 3];
    return [
      b00 * a00 + b01 * a10 + b02 * a20 + b03 * a30,
      b00 * a01 + b01 * a11 + b02 * a21 + b03 * a31,
      b00 * a02 + b01 * a12 + b02 * a22 + b03 * a32,
      b00 * a03 + b01 * a13 + b02 * a23 + b03 * a33,
      b10 * a00 + b11 * a10 + b12 * a20 + b13 * a30,
      b10 * a01 + b11 * a11 + b12 * a21 + b13 * a31,
      b10 * a02 + b11 * a12 + b12 * a22 + b13 * a32,
      b10 * a03 + b11 * a13 + b12 * a23 + b13 * a33,
      b20 * a00 + b21 * a10 + b22 * a20 + b23 * a30,
      b20 * a01 + b21 * a11 + b22 * a21 + b23 * a31,
      b20 * a02 + b21 * a12 + b22 * a22 + b23 * a32,
      b20 * a03 + b21 * a13 + b22 * a23 + b23 * a33,
      b30 * a00 + b31 * a10 + b32 * a20 + b33 * a30,
      b30 * a01 + b31 * a11 + b32 * a21 + b33 * a31,
      b30 * a02 + b31 * a12 + b32 * a22 + b33 * a32,
      b30 * a03 + b31 * a13 + b32 * a23 + b33 * a33,
    ];
  },

  translation: function(tx, ty, tz) {
    return [
       1,  0,  0,  0,
       0,  1,  0,  0,
       0,  0,  1,  0,
       tx, ty, tz, 1,
    ];
  },

  xRotation: function(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

    return [
      1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, c, s, 0,
      0, -s, c, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  yRotation: function(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

    return [
      c, 0, -s, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      s, 0, c, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  zRotation: function(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

    return [
       c, s, 0, 0,
      -s, c, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  scaling: function(sx, sy, sz) {
    return [
      sx, 0,  0,  0,
      0, sy,  0,  0,
      0,  0, sz,  0,
      0,  0,  0,  1,
    ];
  },

  translate: function(m, tx, ty, tz) {
    return m4.multiply(m, m4.translation(tx, ty, tz));
  },

  xRotate: function(m, angleInRadians) {
    return m4.multiply(m, m4.xRotation(angleInRadians));
  },

  yRotate: function(m, angleInRadians) {
    return m4.multiply(m, m4.yRotation(angleInRadians));
  },

  zRotate: function(m, angleInRadians) {
    return m4.multiply(m, m4.zRotation(angleInRadians));
  },

  scale: function(m, sx, sy, sz) {
    return m4.multiply(m, m4.scaling(sx, sy, sz));
  },

};
// m4 ends


  /*
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context
   */
  function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript, theSource, currentChild, shader;

    shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!shaderScript) {
      return null;
    }

    theSource = "";
    currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while (currentChild) {
      if (currentChild.nodeType == currentChild.TEXT_NODE) {
        theSource += currentChild.textContent;
      }

      currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
      // Unknown shader type
      return null;
    }
    gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);

// Compile the shader program
    gl.compileShader(shader);

// See if it compiled successfully
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>


<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="3d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="3d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-helper.js"></script>
```

My version of the pen is [here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdEmMy)

It would be great if somebody could help me fix this error.

Comment: The code you posted above does not get the error you mentioned

Comment: @gman okay I am confused about a few things here. the codepen link has exact code as pasted above - yet I see that error in the console, whereas it executes here. I got help with identifying my codepen error - I defined buffer twice, which on removing, executes the code. My second doubt is, why is the viewport appearing snipped? I used the same logic as the tutorial - so the context should be same?

Comment: The code isn't the same on your codepen. You have more code you added at the top. It's not clear which tutorial you are referencing. The link in your question leads to a blank codepen. You probably needed to click "Save". Assuming it was [this sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWyGZp) then some other differences from your sample are you didn't include the CSS and you didn't call the function `webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);` which is [described here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html) if you want to write your own.

Comment: @gman, sorry about the confusion, I edited the question to point to the correct link of the example I was trying to create. I have attached my version of the pen at the bottom, below the pasted code.

Comment: I updated the snippet above to have the code from your pen, now it gets the error you mentioned. Just linking is not that useful because if you fix the code at the link the question will become irrelevant to other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> Cannot read property 'projection' of undefined at createVertices.

means that `projection` is undefined when you try to use it. This is because `m4.projection`is defined later int he script.

To solve this problem, you should do the declarations at the begin of the script and the function calls at the end.
Move the following code at the very and of the script:

```
initGL();
createShaders();
createVertices();
```

When you do so, you'll get the next error:

> GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

This is because when you call

```
gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
```

the currently boud `ARRAY_BUFFER` is `positionBuffer`, which is empty. I assume you wanted to bind `buffer`.
Remove the following lines to solve this:

```
var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
```

Comment: thanks @rabbid76, this got rid of the error, but I see a warning : `[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7fabe8cc6400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0` . . Also, the image does not yet appear

Comment: Thank you so much @rabbid76, for pointing out the repeated definition! I am yet to get 100% familiar with all the important functions.